# Android studio: How to convert arabic date format to english one?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, date, arabic

I'm tracking my user's login, for most of the world it's ok, but for arabic it's write in arabic letters.
My java code is:

```
Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat sdfAmerica = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
sdfAmerica.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Jerusalem"));
String sDateInAmerica = sdfAmerica.format(date);
```

[image]

Please help...

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Are you tracking the login time as text? Why? If you need to do that, consider using [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce any Arabic digits from your code.

Comment: Your code does involve any Arabic text. Voting to close as unclear.